# Note9: Can you sync DIFFERENT calendars on google calendar and samsung calendar at the same time?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, samsung-galaxy-note-9

I have personal and business calendars from completely different accounts and I don't want them to show on both apps.

When I select specific calendars for Google calendar for Android, I can't prevent Samsung Calendar from showing the exact same changes and vice versa.

Can you select only Calendar A from Account A on one calendar app and only Calendar B from Account B on another on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As strange as this may seem, it is not possible to do that. Any calendars you enable/disable in the Samsung calendar will be reflected in the Google calendar.

However, you can get two separate installations of the calendar by using secure folder. I am a fan of this solution because it keeps all of your business stuff separated from your personal stuff.

1. Enable secure folder by finding the icon on the phone's dropdown menu (above the notification drawer).
2. Launch the secure folder app.
3. Sign into your business Google account in the secure folder settings menu.
4. Open the Samsung Calendar app which should be in secure folder by default, or add a copy of Google Calendar to the secure folder and use that.

You now have two separate calendar apps on your phone and neither is aware of the other's existence.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.knox.securefolder

Comment: @Rhyknowscerious Yes. It should already be installed on your Note 9. You have to enable it via the options on your notification drawer.  Drag down from the top of your screen and you'll see buttons for wifi / bluetooth / etc.  Expand that list and find "secure folder".  Once you enable that option, then an app called "secure folder" will appear in your app drawer and you can install a 2nd version of any app in there.

Answer (score 1):

Candl Apps makes two calendar widgets - one called Calendar Widget: Month and another called Calendar Widget: Agenda.

You can add calendars to these widgets which will not automatically change the visible calendars on other calendar apps.

Here are the links to the play store:

Month
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.candl.chronos

Agenda
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.candl.auge